# How do i can seed the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have a following survey class:

```
    public class SurveyEntity : IIdentity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }    
    public List<SurveyQuestionEntity> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

And UserEntity class:

```
    public class UserEntity:IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<SurveyEntity> Surveys { get; set; }
}
```

This is my On OnModelCreating method in my DbContext class:

```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SurveyQuestionUserAnswerEntity>()
            .HasOne(x => x.SurveyQuestion);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity>()
            .HasData(
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 1, Answer = "4" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 2, Answer = "7" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 3, Answer = "9" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 4, Answer = "Park Forest" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 5, Answer = "Cycling Running" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 6, Answer = "Pizza Burger" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 7, Answer = "Patryk" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 8, Answer = "300km" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 9, Answer = "12" },
            new SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity() { Id = 10, Answer = "444" });


        modelBuilder.Entity<UserEntity>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Surveys)
            .WithOne(x => x.User);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SurveyQuestionEntity>()
            .HasData(
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Type = "numeric",
                Question = "How many people live in this house ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Type = "numeric",
                Question = "How do you rate healthcare in our country ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 3,
                Type = "numeric",
                Question = "How do you rate today's weather ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 4,
                Type = "multiple",
                Question = "Favourite places to spend free time ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 5,
                Type = "multiple",
                Question = "Favourite sports ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 6,
                Type = "multiple",
                Question = "Favourite food ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 7,
                Type = "open",
                Question = "What's your name ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 8,
                Type = "open",
                Question = "How far is from Cracow to Warsaw?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionEntity()
            {
                Id = 9,
                Type = "open",
                Question = "4 x 3 ?"
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserEntity>()
            .HasData(
            new UserEntity()
            {
                Id = 4,
                UserName = "Test4",
                NormalizedUserName = "TEST4",
                Email = "test4@mail.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "TEST4@MAIL.COM",
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                PasswordHash = "test123",
                Surveys = new List<SurveyEntity>()
                {
                    new SurveyEntity()
                    {
                         Id = 1,
                         Status = "public",
                         Title = "My first survey",
                         UserId = 4,
                    }
                }
            });


        modelBuilder.Entity<SurveyEntity>()
            .HasMany<SurveyQuestionEntity>(x => x.SurveyQuestions)
            .WithMany(x => x.Surveys)
            .UsingEntity(
            join => join.HasData(
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 1 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 2 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 3 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 4 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 5 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 6 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 7 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 8 },
                new { SurveysId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 9 }));

        modelBuilder.Entity<SurveyQuestionEntity>()
            .HasMany<SurveyQuestionAnswerEntity>(x => x.SurveyQuestionAnswers)
            .WithMany(x => x.SurveyQuestions)
            .UsingEntity(
            join => join.HasData(
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 1, SurveyQuestionsId = 1 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 2, SurveyQuestionsId = 2 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 3, SurveyQuestionsId = 3 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 4, SurveyQuestionsId = 4 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 5, SurveyQuestionsId = 5 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 6, SurveyQuestionsId = 6 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 7, SurveyQuestionsId = 7 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 8, SurveyQuestionsId = 8 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 9, SurveyQuestionsId = 9 },
                new { SurveyQuestionAnswersId = 10, SurveyQuestionsId = 1 }
                ));
    }
```

And when i try to seed The UserEntity initial data with survey i get a following error:

The seed entity for entity type 'UserEntity' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Surveys' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed to 'SurveyEntity' and specify the foreign key values {'UserId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

How can i do it ? Any ideas ?